# Google crawling pages with "/mydomain.com" after the page url

Tags: google, google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, crawl-errors

Google is crawling and indexing my site without any issues. Each post I create I'm fetching in webmaster tools.

I have looked in the crawl errors and for every post I submit for indexing Google is also attempting to crawl the URL with `/example.com` at the end so:

```
http://example.com/new-posy/example.com
```

This is throwing an obvious 404.

My site is built on Wordpress and I'm using the Yoast SEO plugin.

Comment: Have you checked if there are any websites linking to `http://example.com/new-posy/example.com`?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the same issue but sounds familiar to this question - http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/87763/google-fetch-returning-404-pages-that-are-tags-with-a-web-address-added-to-the-e Possibly something to do with tags?